# Implementing Binary Semaphore using atomic<int>

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, semaphore

I have written this code to demonstrate Binary Semaphore using only atomic .

1 thread producer will push 100 elements in the queue initially.

later threads 2 and 3 which is the consumer will run in parallel to consume this queue.

The issue is: I can see the same data/element print by both the threads

BinarySemaphore.cpp

```
std::queue<int> buffer;
int s_data = 1;


struct Semaphore
{
    Semaphore():s_(1)
    {

    }
    void wait()
    {
        while( s_.load() ==  0);    //you will keep waiting here until s_ becomes 1
        s_.fetch_sub(1);
    }

    void signal()
    {
        s_.fetch_add(1);
    }

    private :
    std::atomic<int> s_ ;

};

Semaphore s; 


void producer()
{
    
    while(s_data <= 100)
    {
        s.wait();

        // critical section starts
        {
            
            std::ostringstream oss;
            oss << "Consumer pushing data " << s_data <<endl;

            cout << oss.str();
            
            buffer.push(s_data++);
        }
        // critical section ends

        s.signal();
    }
}

void consumer()
{
    while (1)
    {
        s.wait();
        // critical section starts
        if (!buffer.empty())
        {
            int top = buffer.front();
            buffer.pop();

            std::ostringstream oss;
            oss << "consumer  thread id= " << this_thread::get_id() <<  " reading data = " << top  << endl;
            cout << oss.str();
        }
        // critical section ends
        s.signal();
    }
}




int main()
{
    Semaphore s;

    std::thread prod(producer);

    prod.join();

    std::thread cons1(consumer);
    std::thread cons2(consumer);


    cons1.join();
    cons2.join();

}
```

Comment: Sample wrong output 

consumer  thread id= 3 reading data = 88
**consumer  thread id= 4 reading data = 89
consumer  thread id= 3 reading data = 89**
consumer  thread id= 3 reading data = 90
consumer  thread id= 3 reading data = 91
consumer  thread id= 3 reading data = 92
consumer  thread id= 3 reading data = 93
consumer  thread id= 3 reading data = 94
consumer  thread id= 3 reading data = 95
consumer  thread id= 3 reading data = 96
consumer  thread id= 4 reading data = 97

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to do more then one action on atomic you need check consistency if data was not changed. Other wise you will have a "gap" as point out in other answer.

There is a [compare_exchange](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) which should be used for that:

```cpp
    void wait()
    {
        auto oldValue = s_.load();
        while (oldValue == 0 || !s_.compare_exchange_strong(oldValue, oldValue - 1))
           oldValue = s_.load();
    }
```

Now if `oldValue` is out of date `oldValue` will be updated and new check will be performed (new iteration of loop) and in next iteration condition will be checked again.

Comment: this logic really helped and solved my entire problem. Now when i run producer and consumer threads in parallel it works as per expectation.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You have a "gap" in wait:

```
void wait()
    {
        while( s_.load() ==  0);    //you will keep waiting here until s_ becomes 1
        s_.fetch_sub(1);
    }
```

load() and fetch_sub are atomic by themselves but between the while... load() and fetch_sub() there is a gap. Maybe you should use "exchange" (and evaluate the result): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/exchange or even better use compare_exchange: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange

Comment: With c++20 you could use wait() and notify...

Comment: thanks for pointing out this gap

Comment: @Wolfgang, that would be good advice if OP were writing production-quality code, but this example looks like a learning exercise. It looks as if OP is trying to understand how inter-thread synchronization works at the lowest levels.